# Count name occurances in json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, count

How can I count occurrences of, let's say one name, in `JSON` file. I want to know how many times, lets says name "MICO", appears in `JSON` file and I want to store it in some variable like `var mico=2;`.  My `JSON` file looks like this:

```
[
 {
    "igralec1": "LEON",
    "datum": "Cetrtek - 21. Julij 2016",
    "set1": "4",
    "set2": "6",
    "set3": "6",
    "set4": "-",
    "set5": "-",
    "igralec2": "MICO",
    "set21": "6",
    "set22": "1",
    "set23": "4",
    "set24": "-",
    "set25": "-"
},
{
    "igralec1": "MICO",
    "datum": "Ponedeljek - 11. Julij 2016",
    "set1": "6",
    "set2": "6",
    "set3": "6",
    "set4": "-",
    "set5": "-",
    "igralec2": "PERO",
    "set21": "2",
    "set22": "1",
    "set23": "3",
    "set24": "-",
    "set25": "-"
  }
]
```

Comment: Is the input always an array of flat objects, or could there be nested objects? And are the names of the relevant properties known in advance? (In your example the name "MICO" only appears in the "igralec1" and "igralec2" properties.)

Comment: Objects are always the same as those two. I fill the data from php form.

Comment: All the names are known in advance. And the names can only be in "igralec1" and "igralec2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the JSON has been retrieved (somehow) into a variable called `json`, you would have to parse it to get an array:

```
var array = JSON.parse(json);
```

Although if you've used a jQuery Ajax method to get it jQuery will likely parse it for you so then you could skip that step. Anyway, assuming the parsed data is (one way or another) in a variable called `array`:

```
function searchForWord(word, array) {
  return array.reduce(function(s, o) {
    if (o.igralec1 === word) s++;
    if (o.igralec2 === word) s++;
    return s;
  }, 0);
}

var micoCount = searchForWord("MICO", array); // 2
var peroCount = searchForWord("PERO", array); // 1
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rzmada6p/1/

I used two `if` statements in case both the `igralec1` and `igralec2` properties in the same object could contain the word you're looking for. If you knew it would only ever be one or the other property within any given object then you could do it with one `if` and an or:

```
if (o.igralec1 === searchWord || o.igralec2 === searchWord) s++;
```

Further reading: [the array `.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `RegExp` constructor and `String.match` function:

```
var jsonData= '[{"igralec1": "LEON","datum":"Cetrtek - 21. Julij 2016","set1": "4","set2": "6","set3": "6","set4": "-","set5": "-","igralec2": "MICO","set21": "6","set22": "1","set23": "4","set24": "-","set25": "-"},{"igralec1": "MICO","datum": "Ponedeljek - 11. Julij 2016","set1": "6","set2": "6","set3": "6","set4": "-","set5": "-","igralec2": "PERO","set21": "2","set22": "1","set23": "3","set24": "-","set25": "-"}];';

var getCount = function(jsonData, str){
        var re = new RegExp('\"' + str +'\"', "ig");
        return jsonData.match(re).length;
    };

console.log(getCount(jsonData, "MICO"));  // 2
console.log(getCount(jsonData, "LEON"));  // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function count(data, entry) {
    return data
               .map(obj => 
                   Object
                       .keys(obj)
                       .map(key => obj[key])
                       .filter(item => item === entry)
                       .length)
               .reduce((res, val) => res + val, 0);
}
```

Usage:

```
const data = []; // your array here
console.log(count(data, 'MICO')); // 2
```

If you know keys:

```
function count(data, keys, entry) {
    return data1
               .reduce((res, obj) => 
                   keys.forEach(key => obj[key] === entry && res++) || res, 0);
}
```

Usage:

```
const data = []; // your array here
console.log(count(data, ['igralec1', 'igralec2'], 'MICO')); // 2
```

Note it uses es2015.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery grep function.
The sample code will  be look like this.
I'm assuming your JSON array name is arr
[Working code](https://jsfiddle.net/pqex93oc/)

```
    var array = [
 {
    "igralec1": "LEON",
    "datum": "Cetrtek - 21. Julij 2016",
    "set1": "4",
    "set2": "6",
    "set3": "6",
    "set4": "-",
    "set5": "-",
    "igralec2": "MICO",
    "set21": "6",
    "set22": "1",
    "set23": "4",
    "set24": "-",
    "set25": "-"
},
{
    "igralec1": "MICO",
    "datum": "Ponedeljek - 11. Julij 2016",
    "set1": "6",
    "set2": "6",
    "set3": "6",
    "set4": "-",
    "set5": "-",
    "igralec2": "PERO",
    "set21": "2",
    "set22": "1",
    "set23": "3",
    "set24": "-",
    "set25": "-"
  }
];
var MICO=0;
 var objJson = jQuery.grep(array, function( n, i ) {    
      if(n.igralec1=="MICO" || n.igralec2 =="MICO"){
          MICO++;
        }
    });
     alert(MICO);
```

Comment: What if i want to count sets for MICO. In my case here the sum of mico sets will be mico=29 (6+4+1+6+6+6). And thanks guys your solutions work!